# Getting a percentage charge for currency exchange (applied arithmetic)

Tags: arithmetic

I was doing my homework last night and this question came up and it is really puzzling me, I don't understand how to do this and my teacher is really bad at explaining things to us, I need a little help with this question and an explanation if possible:

> When the exchange rate is €1=US \$1.28, a person changes US \$1920 to euro. A charge is made for this service. What is the percentage charge if the person receives €1462.50?"

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking the tick.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**

1. How much euros can be bought for \$1920, if 1 euro costs \$1.28
2. How much euros were taken by exchange office from euros that can be bought for \$1920, if we get 1462.5 euros?
3. How many percent of the bought euros form point 1. are euros taken by the exchange office?